# How to show that a measurable set $E$, of measure 1, can be expressed as the union of sets $E_{i}$ of measure $1/2^{i}$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

This question seemed relevant to me because it provides an interesting idea about the lebesgue measure. The problem is the following:

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf{R}$ and let $E$ be a measurable set of measure $\lambda(E)=1$. Prove that there exists a sequence of measurable subsets $E_{i}\subset E$ , of measure $\lambda(E_{i}) = 1/2^{i}$, whose union is $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More on Diego's answer.
Define $f(x) = \lambda\big(E \cap (-\infty,x)\big)$.  We must show $f$ is continuous.
In fact, for $x<y$,
$$
0 \le f(y)-f(x) =
\lambda\big(E \cap (-\infty,y)\big) - \lambda\big(E \cap (-\infty,x)\big)
= \lambda\big(E \cap [x,y) \big) \le \lambda\big([x,y)\big) = y-x .
$$
This shows, in fact, that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

---

Note.  In general, to show a function $f$ is continuous it is not enough to show
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right) = f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{n\to\infty} f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) = f(x) .
$$
These are enough in case $f$ is nondecreasing, however, but probably requires additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is to define the function $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ by $f(x) = \lambda (E \cap (-\infty, x))$. We need to show that this functions is continuous and to use the intermediate value theorem in order to construct the sequence $\{E_{i}\}.$

- $\textit{Continuity from below }$: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
  $$
    \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x - \frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(E \cap (-\infty, x - \frac{1}{n})) = \lambda\left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} E \cap (-\infty, x - \frac{1}{n})\right) = \lambda(E \cap (-\infty, x)) = f(x).
  $$
- $\textit{Continuity from above} :$ Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then
  $$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x + \frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda (E \cap (-\infty, x + \frac{1}{n})) = \lambda\left(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} E \cap (-\infty, x + \frac{1}{n})\right) = \lambda(E \cap (-\infty, x]) = \lambda(E \cap (-\infty, x)) = f(x)
  $$

Due to the intermediate value theorem, there exist $x_{i} \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $f(x_{i}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{i} \frac{1}{2^{k}}$. Define $E_{i}$ by
$$
E_{i} = (E \cap (-\infty, x_{i}))-(E \cap (-\infty, x_{i-1})).
$$
Then $\lambda(E_{i}) = 1/2^{i}$ and
$$
\lambda(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \lambda(E_{i}) = 1.
$$
Then we have that $\cup_{i} E_{i} = E - N$, where $N$ is a set of measure zero. So,
$$
\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} (E_{i} \cup N) = E, \quad \lambda (E_{i} \cup N) = \frac{1}{2^i}.
$$